# Have any pre-made .prototxt and .model for recognition of simple shapes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-recognition

I run a program that can track faces using OpenCV Object Tracking by Adrian Rosebrock but what I really need is tracking simples shapes like squares, retangles and circles. Have some way that I can do that without the misfortune of learn to make my own prototxt and model for the program use as parameter?